# Is there a function that combines correlation and convolution?

Tags: correlation, convolution, moving-average, function

I'm actually trying to find some correlations between functions, and i was wondering if there is a function that quantifies **the amount of time we need to shift a curve to have a high correlation with another one**. I've made a higly professional scheme to explain what i mean :

[image]

Here for example, i would like a function that has a peak when x = length of the orange arrow because if we shift the red curve by this length, we get two perfectly aligned sine waves, that are moving exactly in the same direction.

It seems to be a **mix between convolution and correlation**:

- **Convolution** because it gives you a function that reaches it's max when the energy is the highest possible (area under the product of the two functions), so you can detect some shift between two curves.
- **Correlation** because it gives you an idea of how the two curves are moving together...

Have you an idea of what i'm looking for ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: It looks like an optimization problem rather than a statistical analysis. Is finding the optimal shift by usual optimization methods an option?

Comment: Hi @RomainReboulleau, i'm intersted in any possible solution... but i thought that is was a very common problem, and that statistical tools or filters exist...

Comment: Cross-correlation function?  Dynamic time warping?

Comment: The cross-correlation function *is* a convolution!

Comment: @tbertin The standard approach would be to examine the [cross correlation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation) and as whuber says, it is convolution.

Comment: but as i said in my post, convolution doesn't work for this application. For example,  the scheme shows you that the convolution between the green curve and the red one will be the highest if they become greater than 0 at the same time... and it doesn't correspond to the orange arrow

Comment: maybe a function like that (if h and g are the two functions) : f(t) = Correlation(h(.)
,g(.+t)) ????????